# Android WebView Client

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

The webview client in android has public method

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public MyWebViewClient () {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        something_happen_here
    }
}
```

I setWebViewClient to myWebView

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

When I load an URL to myWebView, the method onLoadResource in class MyWebViewClient is loaded twice, i mean it goes to the line "something_happen_here" twice.

Anyone knows why is this happening? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MyWebViewClient()`, create this function for client first:

```
private class BasicWebViewCient extends WebViewClient {  
    @Override   
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {    
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

Where you want to use, implement `BasicWebViewCient` like that:

```
MyWebView1.setWebViewClient(new BasicWebViewCient());
```

Hope this help.